# Get parent activity viewModel from Fragment android

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, viewmodel

Lets say that i have an activity ChatRoomActivity that has its own ViewModel

```
class ChatRoomActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private val chatRoomViewModel: ChatRoomViewModel by viewModels()
```

and this activity contains a ConversationFramgnet. So inside that fragment i want to observe things from ChatRoomActivity so i need the same instance. If i get it using `by viewModels`
i dont get the values that i want. Seems to me that it makes a new instance of ChatRoomViewModel

```
class ConversationFragment : Fragment() {

    private val chatRoomViewModel: ChatRoomViewModel by viewModels()
```

Another idea but not a good one is the do the viewModel public in the Activity and get it from the Fragment through `chatRoomActivity.chatRoomViewModel`
but that does not work either
So how can i do this?

Comment: Use `by activityViewModels()` in your Fragment if you want to gain access to the activity scoped ViewModel.

Comment: Correct answer. Thank you!!